# Node app conversion to Android apk

Tags: android, node.js, apk

Is it possible to build or convert a nodejs web app to an Android apk executable or equivalent?

I came across this repository `https://github.com/node-on-mobile/node-on-android` but I get the following error.

> (unable to open file as zip archive)

when I try to execute the following command

```
node-on-android ./my-app -o my-app.apk -b ./path/to/android/build/tools
```